How can I implement something like a Fn-Lock key for the function keys in kanata?
I need a kanata configuration where the Caps key plays the role of the Function key on a 60% keyboard, but more like a Function-Lock key which stays locked until a non Function related key is pressed.
My current adaption is to extend the arrows layer in cfg_samples/minimal.kbd with all the function related keys and use the Caps key to trigger it rather than the grv key. But the tap-hold system requires me keep the grv down all the time, but prefer a mode I can release it but keep that mode locked until a key not in the Fn group is pressed.
Which mode akin to the tap-hold mode is required for that?

I think you need a (layer-switch ...) for that: https://github.com/jtroo/kanata/blob/main/docs/config.adoc#layer-switch
Quoting from the docs:

This is permanent until a layer-switch to another layer is activated.

